# Qt and dual monitor with touch screen

Tags: multi-monitor, qt, touch

I have a Qt-based program (using eglfs platform), and 2 monitors, one LVDS and the other one is connected by HDMI. The LVDS monitor is a touch screen.
The screen of HDMI is placed to the right of the LVDS screen, both of them have resolution of 1024x768.
If I touch on the LVDS on the position of (X;Y), the system thinks I have touched on (X*2;Y).
I have tried this command:

`xinput set-prop "eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3000-5207-45.00.00" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`

This works if the software is not Qt-based (like an xterm window), but my Qt software is still wrong.
What is the problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If your using eglfs I believe you might need to configure some of the screen positions/locations via a JSON file passed to the `QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG` environment variable.

Check the documentation on eglfs here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html

For the screen position and touch position read the `Display Output` and `Touch input in systems with multiple screens on KMS/DRM`.

On another note, if you don't want to define external variables to the application all the time you can do the following on your C/C++ main, before your `QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);` is called.

```cpp
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        qputenv("QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG", <path to your qpa json file>);
        
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
        
        ...
```

Hope this helps